# Grok pattern for Apache Catalina logs

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, logstash, logstash-grok

I have some apache catalina logs which look something like this:

```
[22/Jul/2016:09:22:37 +0000] 10.10.29.1 - GET GET /static/s/en/providerLayer_ROOT.js HTTP/1.1  200 6298 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36 https://wpqa.test.com/app/prov/provSelectAccount.htm
[22/Jul/2016:09:22:37 +0000] 10.10.29.1 - GET GET /static/s/en/gregorian.js HTTP/1.1  200 4987 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36 https://wpqa.test.com/app/prov/provSelectAccount.htm
```

How can I write a grok pattern to match these.  I looked around online a bit, but I wasn't able to find too much.  I tried:

```
match => [ "message", "%{TOMCATLOG}", "message", "%{CATALINALOG}" ]
```

But want to get more granular with the details.

```
[22/Jul/2016:09:22:37 +0000] --is date time
10.10.29.1                   --is Ip address
GET GET                      --HTTP Method
/static/s/en/providerLayer_ROOT.js -- Request
HTTP/1.1                     --Protocol Version
200                          --HTTP Status
6298                         --Response time
HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36  --Browser info
https://wpqa.test.com/app/prov/provSelectAccount.htm -- Called URL
```

Trying to break this out has eluded me completely and no matter the regex I keep getting _grokparsefailures.   Am I missing something in my pattern file?

Thanks,

Comment: What flavor regex engine does it use? Example: _Perl_,_Pcre_,_Java_

Comment: Oniguruma regex -- Specificaly for Grok / Logstash and such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following grok filter and it worked perfectly for your log:

```
%{SYSLOG5424SD:timestamp} %{IPV4:IP} - %{CRON_ACTION:HTTPMETHOD}%{URIPATH:request} %{NOTSPACE:protocolVersion}  %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER:responseTime} %{NOTSPACE:browserinfo} %{NOTSPACE:browserinfo} (?<browserinfo>(\((.*)\))) %{NOTSPACE:browserinfo} %{NOTSPACE:browserinfo} %{URI:calledURL}
```

Here is the output:

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    [
      "[22/Jul/2016:09:22:37 +0000]"
    ]
  ],
  "IP": [
    [
      "10.10.29.1"
    ]
  ],
  "HTTPMETHOD": [
    [
      "GET GET "
    ]
  ],
  "request": [
    [
      "/static/s/en/gregorian.js"
    ]
  ],
  "protocolVersion": [
    [
      "HTTP/1.1"
    ]
  ],
  "status": [
    [
      "200"
    ]
  ],
  "responseTime": [
    [
      "4987"
    ]
  ],
  "browserinfo": [
    [
      "HTTP/1.1",
      "Mozilla/5.0",
      "Chrome/51.0.2704.103",
      "Safari/537.36"
    ],
    [
      "(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
    ]
  ],
  "calledURL": [
    [
      "https://wpqa.test.com/app/prov/provSelectAccount.htm"
    ]
  ]
}
```

You can use grok debugger to debug your grok filters [here](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) 
You can use the grok constructor on this [link](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/construction)